# UNION SELECT MySQL query, do math and display in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, select, union

I have 3 tables.  Looking for a good way to find the difference in field `PRICE` using three different tables, then displaying the top 3 largest negative differences.  I want to first find the best MySQL query to use, and also find the best way to display it all in php.

MAINTABLE:

```
COMPANY       | MODEL    | PRICE
Main Company  | ProductA | 100.00
Main Company  | ProductB | 50.00
Main Company  | ProductC | 25.00
Main Company  | ProductD | 300.00
```

COMPTABLE1:

```
COMPANY     | MODEL    | PRICE
Competitor1 | ProductA | 100.00 //0
Competitor1 | ProductB | 55.00 //5
Competitor1 | ProductC | 50.00 //25
Competitor1 | ProductD | 200.00 //-100
```

COMPTABLE2:

```
COMPANY     | MODEL    | PRICE
Competitor2 | ProductA | 99.00 //-1
Competitor2 | ProductB | 44.00 //-6
Competitor2 | ProductC | 20.00 //-5
Competitor2 | ProductD | 100.00 //-200
```

**So the largest negative differences in PRICE which I want displayed in my page are:**

1. Competitor2 ProductD -200 difference from Main Company ProductD
2. Competitor1 ProductD -100 difference from Main Company ProductD
3. Competitor2 ProductB -6 difference from Main Company ProductB

**IDEA:** I am not so familar with it, but I could use a ..`UNION SELECT` on the three tables `WHERE MODEL=XXX`.  I could possibly loop through each one gathering the data, doing the math and spitting out the info.  Only problem is, is that I don't know how to store EACH variable as their own price for each of the tables.  Also, I think it would display ALL differences unless there is a way to store each variable after doing the math, then displaying the top 3 differences.

Any ideas or suggestions to best tackle this query would be appreciated.  (Note:  No I cannot put them all in one table =p )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't help on the PHP side, but this query should get you what you need.  You'll have to do a union to get all the qualified results.  This will have all columns available and pre-calculated for you to put into a simple grid listing in whatever fashion you need.  Since the calculations are competitor vs main company, the PriceDifference via natural order by will have largest negative first, then go positive.  So, the LIMIT command will be applied after the ordering and just send back 3 records.

```
select 
      MT.Model,
      MT.Company as MainCompany,
      MT.Price as MainPrice,
      CT1.Company as Competitor,
      CT1.Price as CompPrice,
      CT1.Price - MT.Price as PriceDifference
   from
      MainTable MT
         JOIN CompTable1 CT1
            on MT.Model = CT1.Model
UNION
select 
      MT.Model,
      MT.Company as MainCompany,
      MT.Price as MainPrice,
      CT2.Company as Competitor,
      CT2.Price as CompPrice,
      CT2.Price - MT.Price as PriceDifference
   from
      MainTable MT
         JOIN CompTable2 CT2
            on MT.Model = CT2.Model
order by
   PriceDifference
limit 3
```

**Suggestion... The way you have your tables structured is really bad for the long haul.  You should try to normalize you data for more optimal performance.  What happens if you have 100 competitors.  You have duplication all over the place.  Change a model name too.  Here is how I would restructure the tables... not explicit data typing, but conceptually**

```
COMPANY 
   CompanyID     auto-increment
   CompanyName   character

PRODUCT
   ProductID     auto-increment
   ProductModel  character

VendorPricing
   VPriceID      auto-increment
   CompanyID     (ID pointing to company table -- to get name when needed)
   ProductID     (ID pointing to product table -- to get model name too)
   Price         actual price for this particular company and product
```

Then, with appropriate indexes, if you wanted to get pricing from one vendor to another, and whatever model, your query could be easier to expand in the future... something like

```
select 
      VP1.CompanyID,
      C1.CompanyName as MainCompany,
      C2.CompanyName as Competitor,
      P1.ProductModel,
      VP1.Price as MainPrice,
      VP2.Price as CompetitorPrice,
      VP2.Price - VP1.Price as PriceDifference
   from
      VendorPricing VP1

         JOIN Company C1
            on VP1.CompanyID = C1.CompanyID

         JOIN Product P1
            on VP1.ProductID = P1.ProductID

         JOIN VendorPricing VP2
            on VP1.ProductID = VP2.ProductID
           AND NOT VP1.CompanyID = VP2.CompanyID

           JOIN Company C2
              on VP2.CompanyID = C2.CompanyID

   where
      VP1.CompanyID = TheOneCompanyYouAreInterestedIn
   order by
      PriceDifference
   limit 3
```

So now, if you had 2, 5, 10 or 100 competitors, the query is exactly the same.

Comment: Beautiful.  So far it works on all tests I performed, thank you.

Comment: @ToddN, although this works across ALL products, if you wanted a list of competitors for a specific single model, I would just add that to as a WHERE clause to each union...  OR, if you wanted top 3 per Model, that too would be a different query.

Comment: Thank you I can do all sorts of "TOP.." queries with this methodology

Comment: @ToddN, per discussion with another on this, I thought I'd expand my answer to help prevent future bottle-necks based on your database relationships and how you might better improve for the future considerations.  Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN C1.Price<C2.Price THEN C1.COMPANY ELSE C2.COMPANY END AS company, 
       M.Model, 
       CASE WHEN C1.Price<C2.Price THEN C1.Price-M.Price ELSE C2.Price-M.Price END AS diff
FROM MAINTABLE M, COMPTABLE1 C1, COMPTABLE2 C2
WHERE M.Model=C1.Model AND M.Model=C2.Model
ORDER BY diff ASC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select mt1.company, tt1.company, mt1.price, tt1.price, (mt1.price - tt1.price) as delta
from mt1
    -- treats tables as single table and allows you flexibility to add more later
    left join (
    select company, model, price from t1
    union
    select company, model, price from t2
    ) tt1 on tt1.model = mt1.model
order by  (mt1.price - tt1.price) 
limit 3 -- actually should be parameter to sproc
```

You need to think about nulls and missing values.  You didn't specify anything, so I didn't handle them either.

Someone earlier mentioned bad performance on mysql doing calculations. This sort of thing is exactly what databases were designed to do.  Poor performance from mysql has more to do with it not being 'smart' and automatically creating an optimized plan like sql server, postgres, or oracle would.  One thing you can do to optimize here is to make sure the price columns are numeric and the model column is indexed in each table.

off-topic - but when you hear about google using mysql - they having teams of dba gurus who optimize their systems.  smaller shops are probably better off with sql server express (free) or postgres (open source).

Comment: Yes, yours may look more efficient, however, your inner query of unioning the companies, models, and prices, but can get performance hit with no utilization of indexes on a derived/union table.  Under certain circumstances, I too will go the route of a union as you have here, but only when a known criteria to prevent a full table joined with a full table.  Respectfully differences of opinion, yet am sure both would work.

Comment: good point drapp.  if the derived table becomes a performance problem, i'd create an indexed view.  really it seems that the 2 customer tables are not designed properly and should be a single table anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad idea to make heavy computations in mysql. In our project we have very hard time to optimise mysql part of our game. And best decision was to compute hard math in php code then in mysql. So on your place i'd like to code it in php and use mysql only for simple queries and some joins.